# How do I add different product everytime while load testing my e-commerce site using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Okay So I have prepared a load test for my shopping website where user starts from homepage and reaches cart via category and catalog. Now I want to send say 10 request where every time I want to add different product. How should I do that.? I am not able to add different product for each request cycle.

Answer (score 1):

**you need CSV data set config - Parameterisation**

Record one test with end to end functionality.
then find requests where user is selecting category and product based on category 
then you can parameterize that request for category,product (your users also)

Create a csv file like (without header, I have shown for example),

```
username,pwd,category,product
a1,a1,tv,lg
a2,a2,mobile,sony
```

etc. now use CSV data config from Jmeter data config options and set the values 
i.e name of csv file, fields, seperator, should be used by all threads

and substitute `${username},${category}` etc. in particular request.

Thus if you run test with 2 threads then first thread will pickup values from first line and second thread will use second line.

Refer : http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config

Comment: Thanks nachiket but I am sending different form data while adding the product to cart for every product. How do I handle it? ie for POST requests and headers

Comment: post some request snapshots and elaborate your question. question is not making it clear to understand and answer.